# Validator function in Backbone

Tags: javascript, beginner, validation, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have inside a Backbone model `validate` function several `if` statements:

```
if(!attrs.firstAttr) errorMsg+="first attr mandatory";
if(!attrs.secondAttr) errorMsg+="second attr mandatory";
```

as you can see there is a lot of repetition (I have actually 10 fields to check with this.

I was thinking of introducing an *interface* `Validator` with a method `validate`. Then implement a `MandatoryFieldValidator` with:

```
validate: function(attr, errors) {
   if(!attr) errors.push(attr + " mandatory");
}
```

So the validate method would become like this:

```
mandatoryFieldValidator.validate(attr.firstAttr, errors); // errors now is an array
mandatoryFieldValidator.validate(attr.secondAttr, errors);
```

Would you think is a good solution? I still don't like it because I need to rewrite it a lot of times. Next step would be to have some kind of `foreach` but I don't have a list of parameters. The attributes passed by the Backbone validate is an object with the properties of the model.

Would it be ok to declare an array with every element I want to validate like `[attr.firstAttr, attr.secondAttr]`?

If yes, how would it be possible to do it in Backbone? I'm referring to the fact that [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) function from underscore.js just passes an array with a callback function and I still need to pass the *error* array and apply the `validate` method of my `Validator`.

Comment: Have you tried to use Backbone.Validation plugin? It helps a lot!  https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation

Comment: @Juliano I know that plugin but my problem is that part of the validation needs to happen only when certain conditions are met. If I recall correctly, with Backbone.Validation you can't do that.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but in general, providing us the real code with the 10 fields helps us finding a better answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would approach that like this:

Have an array with all the fields you

```
var mandatoryFields = ['firstAttr','secondAttr'];
```

Then have a validate function that takes `attrs`, `mandatoryFields` and `errors`

```
function validate( o , mandatoryFields, errors )
{
  for( var i = 0 , i < mandatoryFields.length ; i++ )
  {
    var field = mandatoryFields[i];
    if(!o[field]) 
      errors.push(field + " mandatory");
  }
}
```

Note that I replaced `attrs` with `fields` but fare more readable, I also added a new-line  after that `if` statement for readability.